# Connection string encryption in Identity Server

Tags: identity-server

We  had implemented the federated authentication as part of Sitecore 9.2.

We need to encrypt the connection string present in **Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml** of the Identity Server. Is there a way to do it

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I need 15 rep points to upvote and 50 to comment

Comment: @GeoffHarden its easy to get 100 points - just sign up for another Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow site with your SSE account and you will have the points.